# jQuery changing font - same space occupied

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts

Is there a way that when I change the whole page font, I could keep the same design? I added an option to my website for the user to change the font of the entire website, but there is quite a bit of difference between the aspect of the website.

I have to manually change the elements when changing fonts or there is a simpler way to do that?

Comment: In short, don't try to do this. If it's mostly about big header text take a look at a JavaScript library like http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the font to a comparable size (width & height) of the previous font.

For example... `Arial` (font size of 12px) is roughly the same as `Veranda` (font size of 11px) in height, but not width. Verdana is naturally a wider font. So those two wouldn't be the most compatible.

Comment: That is a tough question. Impact is narrow and tall, and Comic Sans is wider and taller. You might want to pick out a few elements on your page to have the font change, instead of everything. This provides the different look, but keeps things relatively simple. Second suggestion...rework your HTML/CSS to accommodate for the variation of text size so the site maintains it's look no matter how big/narrow/short/wide the font it.